# Extension of hypercube

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I understand the notion of a hypercube as a graph with vertex set $\{0,1\}^{n}$ and an edge between two vertices if their vertices differ in one co-ordinate is there an extensive body of work on the case where we have vertex set $\{1,2,...,r\}^{n}$ with edges between two vertices that differ in exactly one co-ordinate? How about when the vertex set is $\{1,2,...,n\}^{n}$? I am particularly interested in the final case, i've tried different searches but i have no idea what this type of graph maybe called.

Answer (score 4):

Your graph is called the [Hamming graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_graph) $H(n,r)$. It can also be written $(K_r)^{\Box n}$, the $n$th [Cartesian power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) of the [complete graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) on $r$ vertices.

Comment: Ok and what would the graph be known as if the vertex set was a subset of $\{1,2,...,r\}^{n}$ but not necessarily the whole set?

Comment: @PavanSangha: I'm not sure it would have a nice name in that case.